# Can't pull image from private docker registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry

Trying to get a private repo running on my EC2 instance so my other docker hosts created by docker-machine can pull from the private repo. I've disabled SSL and have put up a firewall to compensate that allows my test server(the one I'm trying to pull on) to connect to my main EC2 instance (the private repo). So far I can push to the private repo where it's hosted on my main EC2 instance (was getting an EOF error before disabling SSL) but I get the following error when I run this on my text server:

`docker pull ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:5000/scoredeploy`

this is the error it spits out:

`Error response from daemon: Get https://ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:5000/v1/_ping: EOF`

Googling this error on yields results of people having similar issues, but without any fixes.
Anybody have any idea of what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to set the `--insecure-registry <registry-ip>:5000` flag on the docker daemon's startup command on your non-docker-registry machine. In your case: `--insecure-registry ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:5000`

If you want to use your already-running docker machine, this should help you out setting the flag: https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/#/deploying-a-plain-http-registry

If you're using boot2docker, the file location and format is slightly different. Give this a shot if this is the case: http://www.developmentalmadness.com/2016/03/09/docker-configure-insecure-registry-in-boot2docker/

I've had issues with my docker machines not saving this setting on reboots. If you run into that issue, I'd recommend you make a new machine including the flag `--engine-insecure-registry <registry-ip>:5000` in the `docker-machine create` command.

Best of luck!